# Search data based on timestamp with multiple joins and dependency between timestamp in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-timestamp

I have two tables `prod_replay_in` and `prod_replay_out`as below.

For `msg_type` as CDST010 in `prod_replay_in` table has it's confirmation in `prod_replay_out` table as `CDST01C`. Same for `msg_type` as CDST100 has it's confirmation message in `prod_replay_out` table as `CDST10C`. In below tables, `cdsx_time` matters. For example, second CDST100 message will have second `CDST10C` message based on `cdsx_time`.

**Note:** JOIN between 2 tables is based on `cdsx_id` as it is common between two tables. CDST010 and `CDST01C` will have only one entry for same `cdsx_id` in `prod_replay_in` and `prod_replay_out` table respectively. Also, number of CDST100 and `CDST10C` messages varies based on `cdsx_id`.

**What I want to search?**

I want to search number of CDST100 messages in `prod_replay_in` table as per following criteria:

- Get 1st CDST100 if fourth character in `bancs_msg` for CDST100 is matched with fourth character in `msg_body` for CDST01C
- Get 2nd CDST100 if fourth character in `bancs_msg` for CDST100 is matched with fourth
  character in `msg_body` for 1st CDST10C
- Get 3rd CDST100 if fourth character in bancs_msg for CDST100 is matched with fourth character
  in `msg_body` for 2nd CDST10C

The above pattern is like checking 2nd CDST100 with first CDST10C, 3rd CDST100 with 2nd CDST10C, etc.

**prod_replay_in**

```
id(serial) | msg_type(varchar) | cdsx_time(timestamp)  | cdsx_id(varchar)    | bancs_msg(text)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8334698    | CDST010           | 2020-02-24 14:23:01.0 | T202005518525        | ABCD
8341809    | CDST100           | 2020-02-24 14:47:38.0 | T202005518525        | ANOC
8342732    | CDST100           | 2020-02-24 14:51:53.0 | T202005518525        | PHLM
8344890    | CDST100           | 2020-02-24 15:15:14.0 | T202005518525        | JKQO
```

**prod_replay_out**

```
    id(serial) | msg_type(varchar) | cdsx_time(timestamp)    | cdsx_id(varchar)     | msg_body(text)
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    42164527   | CDST01C           | 2020-02-24 14:23:08.016 | T202005518525        | AQRS
    42176068   | CDST10C           | 2020-02-24 14:47:47.056 | T202005518525        | STUM
    42177522   | CDST10C           | 2020-02-24 14:52:00.031 | T202005518525        | XYZK
    42245814   | CDST10C           | 2020-02-24 15:30:00.045 | T202005518525        | ASQO
```

**What I have tried?**

I have tried creating sql query for matching 1st CDST100 and CDST01C but not sure how can I compare with subsequent CDST100 with CDST10C?

```
SELECT count(T.id) FROM prod_replay_in T JOIN prod_replay_out O ON T.CDSX_ID = O.CDSX_ID
  JOIN prod_replay_out K ON K.CDSX_ID = O.CDSX_ID
  WHERE T.MSG_TYPE = 'CDST100'
  and O.msg_type = 'CDST01C'
  and K.msg_type = 'CDST10C'
  and ( (
        min(T.cdsx_time) > O.cdsx_time
        and substr(T.bancs_msg,4,1) = substr(O.msg_body,4,1)
        )
      );
```

Comment: Is every `prod_replay_in` record guaranteed to have a corresponding `prod_replay_out` record in your data?

Comment: @MikeOrganek Yes, `cdsx_id` will be for both tables. If not, I am not considering it for my search query as I used JOIN in sql.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried following code. It should work as per my knowledge. Please feel free to suggest if any scenarios are missing.

```
Select count(T.*) from PROD_REPLAY_IN T, PROD_REPLAY_OUT O
Where T.msg_type = 'CDST100'
AND O.msg_type IN ('CDST01C', 'CDST10C')
AND T.cdsx_id = O.cdsx_id
AND substr(T.bancs_msg,4,1) = substr(O.msg_body,4,1)
AND (O.cdsx_id, O.cdsx_time) IN (Select Y.cdsx_id, Max(Y.cdsx_time) from PROD_REPLAY_OUT Y
        Where Y.msg_type IN ('CDST01C', 'CDST10C')
        AND O.cdsx_id = Y.cdsx_id
        AND T.cdsx_time > Y.cdsx_time
        GROUP BY Y.cdsx_id
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

So long as you know that there will be a corresponding `prod_replay_out` row for every `prod_replay_in` row by timestamps, you can set this up to use window functions to sidestep the different message types at the beginning of a replay:

```
with interleave as (
  select msg_type, cdsx_time, cdsx_id, bancs_msg as msg, 'in' as direction
    from prod_replay_in
  union all
  select msg_type, cdsx_time, cdsx_id, msg_body as msg, 'out' as direction
    from prod_replay_out
), match_cdst100 as (
  select cdsx_id, msg,
         lag(msg) over (partition by cdsx_id
                            order by cdsx_time) as last_msg
    from interleave
   where msg_type = 'CDST100'
)
select cdsx_id, count(*) 
  from match_cdst100
 where substr(msg, 4, 1) = substr(last_msg, 4, 1)
 group by cdsx_id;
```

Comment: It shows error as `Error: ERROR: column "match_cdst100.cdsx_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 442
SQLState:  42803
ErrorCode: 0`

Comment: @JayParmar  I updated the answer to include the `group by`